# Pattern matching Enum.map vs case condition

Tags: pattern-matching, elixir

I have this map:

```
%{
  "a" => "1",
  "b" => "2",
  "c" => "3",
  "d" => "4",
  "e" => %{"f" => "5"}
}
```

And I can iterate its key value like this:

```
Enum.map(map, fn({k, v}) ->  
  v
end)
```

Using fn`({k, v})` like a tuple and I obtain something like this:

```
["1", "2", "3", "4", %{"f" => "5"}]
```

But I dont understand why this doesnt work:

```
Enum.map(map, fn({k, v}) ->  
  case v do
    {key, value} -> "inner map"
    _ -> "something else"
end)
["something else", "something else", "something else", "something else",
 "something else"]
```

I can pattern match the map with `fn({k, v})` but I cant use the same pattern match for the case condition?

**Update**

That's what I am trying

```
some = %{"a" => "1", "b" => "2", "c" => "3", "d" => "4", "e" => %{"f" => "5"}}
Enum.map(some, fn({k, v}) ->       
  case v do                        
    %{^condition => value} -> "inner map"
    _ "something else"
  end
end)
** (CompileError) iex:15: unknown variable ^condition. No variable "condition" has been defined before the current pattern
    (stdlib) lists.erl:1354: :lists.mapfoldl/3
```

Comment: What is `condition`?!

Comment: I would like to patterh matching condition as a key and value as the value, so I can use it like "#{condition} ... #{key}" but I am afraid is not possible right? I must always know the key name to do that

Comment: Yes, the key is mandatory. If you are positive there is the only key-value pair, you might convert it to `Keyword` and pattern match it: `%{} = map -> [{key, value}] = Map.to_list(map)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`{key, value}` is not a **map**, it’s a **tuple**. You need:

```rb
Enum.map(map, fn({k, v}) ->  
  case v do
    %{} = map -> "inner map: #{inspect map}"
    _ -> "something else"
  end
end)
#⇒ ["something else", "something else",
#   "something else", "something else",
#   "inner map: %{\"f\" => \"5\"}"]
```

---

Whether the existence of a key is proven, one might pattern match it’s value directly (note pinned `key`):

```rb
key = "f"
Enum.map(map, fn({k, v}) ->  
  case v do
    %{^key => v} -> "inner map with value: #{inspect v}"
    _ -> "something else"
  end
end)
#⇒ ["something else", "something else",
#   "something else", "something else",
#⇒  "inner map with value: \"5\""]
```

Comment: mm if I know that map always has just a key, can I pattern match it somehow like  %{key => value} ?

Comment: Updated an answer.

Comment: I tried that but I am receiving unknown variable ^key. No variable "key" has been defined before the current pattern

Comment: Please copy-paste the whole snippet. Note the first line is `key = "f"`. You might just use `%{"f" => v}` but I wanted to show the most generic example.

Comment: I meant _copy-paste my snippet_. One might [pin](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#%5E/1) the existing variable only.

Comment: ah you are right, I totally didnt see key = "f", makes sense